# Match within a Range of two fields from an Array of Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of numbers `[111, 444, 777]`

I want to look inside these 2 documents

```
{
  _id: 1,
  lookHere: {rangeLow: 333, rangeHigh: 555}
},
{ 
 _id: 2,
  lookHere: {rangeLow: 222, rangeHigh: 333}
}
```

I want to write a query that returns only the 1st document since my array of numbers includes 444 which is between 333 and 555.

Is there a query that can achieve this result in mongo/mongoose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query. You can [`.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) the source array into the arguments for [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
var inputs =  [111, 444, 777];

collection.find({
  "$or": inputs.map( n => ({ 
    "lookHere.rangeLow": { "$lt": n },
    "lookHere.rangeHigh": { "$gt": n }
  }) )
})
```

That is basically looking to see if the Low value is less than and the High is greater than each of the current elements, and returns as true when any match both those conditions.

Note that all MongoDB query arguments are implicitly AND conditions unless stated otherwise.